# Kotlin: lateinit property has not been initialized when setting TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying to set the text of a `TextView` in a fragment. I am calling a method from my Fragment class in my Pager Adapter to accomplish this, but I receive the following error in doing so:

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property totalMsg has not been initialized
```

In other words, it seems as if the `onCreateView` method is triggered **after** `setTotalMessages` is called:
Below is my Kotlin code for the `TotalFragment` class:

```
class TotalFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var inf:View;
    lateinit var totalMsg:TextView;

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        inf = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.total_fragment, container, false) as View;
        totalMsg = inf.findViewById(R.id.chat_count)
        Log.i("App", "done")
        return inf;
    }

    // Setter method that sets the text of the total messages #
    fun setTotalMessages(messageCount: String) : Unit {
        Log.i("App", "done2")
        totalMsg.text = "total # of messages exchanged: " + messageCount;
        //totalMessages.setText("total # of messages exchanged: " + messageCount);
    }
}
```

Below is my code for the Pager Adapter:

```
class PageAdapter(private val myContext: Context, fm: FragmentManager, internal var totalTabs: Int) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
    // keep track of the fragment containing the cumulative statistics
    var totalFrag:TotalFragment = TotalFragment();

    // this is for fragment tabs
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                return totalFrag
            }
            1 -> {
                return IndividualFragment()
            }
            2 -> {
                // val movieFragment = MovieFragment()
                return UsageFragment()
            }
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    // set the text of the cumulative texts label
    fun setCumulativeTexts(messageCount:Int) {
        totalFrag.setTotalMessages(messageCount.toString());
    }

    // this counts total number of tabs
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return totalTabs
    }
}
```

Below is my Kotlin code for `MainActivity.kt` where I call the method to set the cumulative texts:

```
val adapter = PageAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager, tabLayout!!.tabCount)
adapter.setCumulativeTexts(5)
```

Comment: Because `setTotalMessages` works before `onCreatView`. So your totalMsg does not initialize.

Comment: Where in the code do you init and add `TotalFragment` to container view?

Comment: Explain what do you want to do. I think you can use a more suitable way to achieve your goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only `var` instead of `lateinit var`

```
var inf: View? = null
var totalMsg: TextView? = null
var messageCount: String? = null
```

And use it like below

```
fun setTotalMessages(messageCount: String) : Unit { 
    //store count here
    this.messageCount = messageCount
    totalMsg?.text = "total # of messages exchanged: " + messageCount
}
```

Then after view created try to set the count

```
override fun onCreateView( inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): View? { 
    inf = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.total_fragment, container, false) as View; 
    totalMsg = inf?.findViewById(R.id.chat_count) 

    // set it from here
    totalMsg?.text = "total # of messages exchanged: " + messageCount

    return inf; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked beautifully. A very clever solution!

Comment: Glad to hear that @Adam. Please don't forget to press upvote so that  others can find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
val adapter = PageAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager, tabLayout!!.tabCount)
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter)
adapter.setCumulativeTexts(5)
```

Also can you add code from R.layout.total_fragment as well for better understanding of the problem?

Answer (score -1):

`onCreateView` is called when **inflating** the view. You should rather get references to your views in the `onViewCreated` method (I.e. **after** the view has been inflated)

```
override fun onViewCreated(...) {
    totalMsg = inf.findViewById(R.id.chat_count)
}
```

Comment: After adding print statements to the onViewCreated method, it appears that onViewCreated is never called.

Comment: According the android documentation on fragments, the onViewCreated is "Called immediately after onCreateView"

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)